# Как скрыть меню, после клика на стрелку в низу?

Tags: html, jquery

Как скрыть меню, после клика на стрелочку (которая находится в низу меню) ? Нужно чтобы меню просто исчезло или заехало по левую сторону, а в вверху появилась другая стрелочка, которая показывает меню.

Мой код меню: https://jsfiddle.net/3069jk4o/

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $(".menu-button").click(function(){
        $(".menu-bar").toggleClass( "open" );
  });       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно спрятать ваше меню, а чтобы появилась стрелочка, то аналогичным образом (через `fadeIn()` или `show()` ) показывать её после скрытия этого меню. изначально его создать с `top:0; left:0` и скрыть через `display:none`, например.

```
$('.hide_menu').click(function() {      
        $('.menu').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо разобрался, сделал через `hide()` и `show()`.